# Worker Node relation to Master Node?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, workload

I am working on designing a solution with HA and load distribution.
I have a question about how the relationship can be built between a worker node and master node to support HA (Fault Tolerance) and load distribution.

My understanding that a worker node is managed by a master node which means that during the building of a worker node, we make it join a master node in order to build the trust and link with the master node.

So now if I want to build HA for the cluster on the master node:

- I am going to define 3 master nodes, each has an API server with a loadbalancer in-front of them.
- build ETCD cluster externally having 3 nodes and make the master nodes uses them.
- the 3 master nodes will have each a scheduler.

Going to the worker node:

- I start the worker node by making it join to a master using the VIP/loadbalanced API-server.

So my questions are:

- on the 3 master nodes, should we have a controller?
- Can we link the worker node to the 3 master nodes? if Yes, What is the benefit of that? Isn't it better to use the loadbalancer/VIP? Will, in that case, we still have the limitation of 5000 nodes? or can it be up to 5000X3 worker nodes?
- Can we have a cluster of API-server with active-passive just like we do in etcd? even if we can do it just using a set of configurations in the initialization phase?

Answer (score 0):

> on the 3 master nodes, should we have a controller?

I'm not sure what controller you are talking about (A Kubernetes controller? The kube-controller-manager?). In summary, all the master nodes would have the same Kubernetes components: kube-apiserver, kube-scheduler, kube-controller-manager, kube-proxy, runtime, etc.

> Can we link the worker node to the 3 master nodes? if Yes, What is the benefit of that? Isn't it better to use the loadbalancer/VIP? Will, in that case, we still have the limitation of 5000 nodes? or can it be up to 5000X3 worker nodes?

If you have a 3 master setup, one is active (leader) and the others are in standby, there's only one leader established by a configured [quorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum) for these components, so it's not that you can scale 5000x3 nodes, the limit of 5000 would still apply because you are always talking to the leader.

> Can we have a cluster of API-server with active-passive just like we do in etcd? even if we can do it just using a set of configurations in the initialization phase?

That's the way it works. In a 3 master setup, there's 1 active and 2 passive, in a 5 master set up there 1 active and 5 passive.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am talking about the kube control manager. Now I know that it will run in a leader slave mode, I mean the kube control manager as well the kube schedule. so only one master is leading those.

Yes I was thinking as well that it is not going to scale above the 5000 (the limits of a master node).

I am not sure that kube api server runs in a leader slave cluster that is why I believe we need to put a solution above it to hide the real api server ip or dns.

I was more told by a colleague that  we can have multiple api servers to the same worker node, I have not tried it myself but I truly suspect that it will work and I still believe the option of a DNS server just like Ruote 53 or a Proxy like nigix or even a hardware balancer as F5 should be the possible options to let the worker communicate with the active master without depending on it.